# Проблема с миграцией EntityFramwork в приложении Asp.net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, миграция

Есть приложение

[image: структура приложения]

При попытке Enable-Migrations возникает No context type was found in the assembly 'ToDoList.Web'.[image: Ошибка]

Это связано с тем, что в ToDoList.Web нет класса наследуемого от DbContext, он находится в ToDoList.Domain. Совершаем Enable-Migrations для ToDoList.Domain. Получаем примерно следующее: [image: Ошибка]

Читаем в интернете. Находим что в ToDoList.Domain просто нету строки подключения, но это Class lib так, что добавлять туда ее бессмысленно.
Рекомендуют выполнить Enable-Migrations -StartUpProjectName "ToDoList.Web" -ContextProjectName "ToDoList.Domain". И о чудо, ошибка:
[image: очередная ошибка]

**Вопрос, как исправить данное чудо???**